# Returning a vector of tuples c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to create and return a vector of two element arrays (which I will refer to as tuples), however I am running into issues.

```
std::vector<int *> distr;
int tuple[2];
distr.push_back(tuple);
//modify tuple's contents
distr.push_back(tuple)
```

In this case distr then has two copies of the modified tuple rather than the two distinct tuples I desired.

So I figured it had to do with memory so I tried this approach instead

```
distr.push_back(new int [num1, num2]);
```

But it doesn't save the tuples correctly as trying to access their values returns weird false values.

This is clearly due to a misunderstanding of how memory is allocated. I can understand why the first example fails in that fashion but I do not understand the issue with the second example.

Comment: What about using [`std::tuple<int,int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) or at least `std::pair<int,int>` instead of doing the memory management on your own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use

```
distr.push_back(new int [num1, num2]);
```

You are not creating a a two element array filled with num1, num1. That would be done like the following:

```
new int[2] {num1, num2}
```

I would advise against using this method though.  If all of your tuples will be the same size I would make struct to represent that data type (in the special case of two, you can even use `std::pair`)

Answer (score 3):

Use a pair instead of a pointer:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > distr;
// Do some code
distr.emplace_back(num1, num2);
```

Answer (score 2):

At first, you should understand, that "classic" C and C++ arrays are just buffers of allocated memory. In your sample, `tuple` is just a pointer to allocated buffer of 2 integers. So, when you push_back value of `tuple` you just add the same pointer twice. The array itself is not copied to std::vector, so, you end with vector containing two pointers to the SAME area of memory. To achieve desired behavior, you can use more high-level C++-ish data types, such as [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) or [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Speaking about your second code snippet, it's just syntax misunderstanding: expression `new <type>[<count>]` creates a memory buffer (similar to your `tuple`, but on the HEAP) of  values of type `<type>`. So, if you are going to create buffer of 2 `int`s, you should write `new int[2]`. When you are use `a, b` expression, it evaluates as [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), and `<count>` will be `num2` in your sample.

P.S. Be aware, that to work correct with heap memory you should study C++ memory management much deeper.